# Add filter by year in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a Django model with DateTimeField field as "created_at", now I want to add a filter for that field in Django admin but I need only the year field instead of default fields as (today, past 7 days, this month, this year).

Here's my model:

**In models.py**

```
class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
link = models.URLField(max_length=255,)
relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

I have tried to override created_at field in admin.py as:

```
class TaggedArticle(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['category_fit', 'article', 'link', 'relevant_feedback', 'category', 'user', 'email', 'created_at']
    list_display = ['article_id', 'link', 'user', 'created_at']
    list_filter = ['user', 'email', 'created_at']
    model = Tagged


def created_at(self, obj):
    return self.Tagged.created_at.year

admin.site.register(Tagged, TaggedArticle)
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I achieve that?
Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can add `date_hierarchy = 'created_at'` to your admin class.

```
class TaggedArticle(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'
    fields = ['category_fit', 'article', 'link', 'relevant_feedback', 'category', 'user', 'email', 'created_at']
    list_display = ['article_id', 'link', 'user', 'created_at']
    list_filter = ['user', 'email']
    model = Tagged
```

It also provides the ability to filter by month, day in a better way than implementing it by ourselves.

Comment: Hi @Cai ! it doesn't work, still, display all filter options, I need to display only the year, it should display all year in which any Tagged articles has been created.

Comment: You can remove the created_at from list_filter, the filter would show at the top of all columns.

Comment: it also displays months, how can i display only years?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that, but as there is only year displayed in the first view, it's useful for some cases, and might be overwritten if you need some more advanced usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use [django-daterange-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter) package for filter on year.

And refer [django-list-filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) documentation.

May this helps you

Comment: django-daterange-filter is now very old and doesn't work